# Google Cloud SQL fails to init mysql database after deployment

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

According to Goole App Engine [Documention][1].One can define environment variables in app.yaml like following way.

```
#[START env]
env_variables:
    # Replace USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, and CONNECTION_NAME with the
    # values obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
    MYSQL_USER: ****
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
    MYSQL_DSN: mysql:dbname=s5-users;unix_socket=/cloudsql/s5-app-167912:us-central1:s5-users-db
#[END env]
```

But if I deploy the app it returns me this error.

```
string(84) "mysql:dbname=s5-users-db;unix_socket=/cloudsql/s5-app-167912:us-central1:s5-users-db"
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I exported environment variables with bash and tested the app on localhost with the same database.Everything seems to be fine and I can connect to remote database.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.  Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: try to set  the url in quotes like MYSQL_DSN: 'mysql:dbname=s5-users;unix_socket=/cloudsql/s5-app-167912:us-central1:s5-users-db'